# How to use a condition in a static text field?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using condition to print field values.My condition is if isList == "list" then print value of region_name.Following codes works fine.

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{isList} == "list" ? "" : $F{region_name})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

But now I need to print static text using condition too. When I'am using same method,it doesn't work.It shows "($F" instead of static text.

`<text><![CDATA[($F{isList} == "list" ? "Region:" : "")]]></text>`

[image: Example]

What is wrong ? How I can fix it ?

Comment: The *staticText* is not supported expression. It will be always const. You should use *textField*

Comment: Thank you for your answer ;) I must change it to textField

Comment: @Alex consider to move your comment to an answer (if you do flag this as obsolete). this is probably the reference link http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/text-elements